# use different desktop environments on ubuntu local and for rdesktop

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, kde

I want to access my ubuntu pc locally per gnome-desktop and remotely via rdesktop per kde plasma.

I want to use it parallel with the same user.
I connect via remote desktop from windows and get a login screen. There is a select input field but only Xorg can be chosen.

[image]

How do I configure it?

Comment: How do you connect? Do you use a login manager? Can't you just choose the session when you log in?

Comment: I connect per remote desktop from windows

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include this. Also, explain what you see. When you connect, are you already in a running desktop session or do you need to log in? And if you log in, can't you choose the desired session (Gnome or KDE) there?